# Instance of an empty ("nil") UUID in Java

Tags: java, null, uuid

In Java, how does one generate an instance of an empty/"nil" [java.util.UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) object where all 128 bits are zero?

> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Nil UUIDs are described in:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants_and_versions)
- [Section 4.1.7 of RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.7).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Constructor

Use the constructor taking a pair of `long` integers, both zero.

```
java.util.UUID uuid = new UUID( 0 , 0 );  // Or ( 0L , 0L )
```

## Hex String

You can create a nil UUID from a hex string of zeros in the canonical format.

```
java.util.UUID uuid = UUID.fromString( "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" );
```

## Enum

You could make this handy within your Java app by defining an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) of this and any other special values that have specific meaning within your business logic.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * @author Basil Bourque. Free forever to use at your own risk.
 */
public enum UuidSpecific  {

    NIL( "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ),
    TOLERABLE_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION( "e8e6528b-e43c-468b-b661-e24f1b64bee6" );

    // Members
    private UUID uuid;

    // Constructor
    UuidSpecific ( String uuidHexArg ) {
        this.uuid = java.util.UUID.fromString( uuidHexArg );
    }

    // Getters
    UUID getUuid ( ) {
        return this.uuid;
    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
System.out.println("UuidSpecific.NIL : " + UuidSpecific.NIL.getUuid() );
```

Comment: Or the much easier approach of `new UUID(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.UUID;

UUID.fromString("0-0-0-0-0");
```